# How to run python debugger with a script that takes command-line arguments?

Tags: python, bash, debugging, pdb

I have a python script that takes input arguments and runs in response to the following command in terminal (bash, Mac OSX).

```
python test.py arg1 arg2
```

Is there a good way to run the same script in debug mode without editing the code to include `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()`?

For example, if I'm using iPython console, I can do this by the following:

```
%run -d test.py arg1 arg2
```

This is pretty straightforward, isn't it? To achieve the same thing in terminal, I thought the following might work, but it did not:

```
python -c "import pdb; import sys; sys.argv = ['test.py', arg1, arg2];pdb.run('test.py')"
```

The code ran with the arguments, but not in `pdb`'s debugging mode. Is it just hard to do and I should stick with `pdb.set_trace` or iPython's `%run -d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug a python script wit input arguments in Spyder IDE (2.3.4)

1. **Run** > **Configure**...
2. Select a run configuration > (Choose the script of interest that is open)
3. General settings> **Command line options**: `arg1 arg2 arg3` (use a space as delimiter just as in commandline)
4. Working directory: (Choose the folder)
5. Click **OK**

Then **Debug** from menu. This is equivalent to execute the following in iPython console in Spyder.

```
debugfile('/Users/xxx/xxx/test.py', args='arg1 arg2', wdir='/Users/xxx/xxx/')
```

Doing it with PyCharm is quite similar.

1. Run > **Edit Configurations**
2. Choose the python script from the menu
3. The `Configuration` pane
4. **Script parameters**: `arg1 arg2`

Then Run > **Debug** > Choose the file.

In iPyhton Console you can also try this (suppose test.py is in your current folder):

```
%run -d test.py arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
python -m pdb test.py arg1 arg2
```

Running `python -m pdb` runs [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) as a script. If `test.py` is somewhere in your path rather than your current working directory, this can be a helpful substitute:

```
python -m pdb "$(which test.py)" arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Now I found the description about this sytax in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#module-pdb) which I've been reading many times!

Answer (score 0):

Support you have following code

```
for i in range(200):
    print i
```

You can start debugging by adding

> pdb.set_trace()

example

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(200):
    print i
```

Code will break at

> pdb.set_trace()

once code stops you can use pdb commands to debug it. 
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger for pdb commands.