# Debugging python code in VS Code calling the .py file from the .ipynb cell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, jupyter-notebook, cell

I have many different classes and functions in seperate .py files. I am calling the main.py to trigger whole algorithm using

```
!python main.py --iterNum 100 --gamma 0.8
```

command in another Jupyter Notebook (test.ipynb) file.

I put breakpoints in main.py file to debug it. However, when I run the that command in test.ipynb cell, it does not run in debug mode. How can I debug my code from Jupyter Notebook cell. I want the debugger to go directly the breakpoints whenever I run above command in test.ipynb in VS Code IDE.

I have seen [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560904/debug-a-python-script-with-arguments-from-terminal). I got below error.

> error: unrecognized arguments: -m pdb

Comment: I decided to do it in Spyder utilizing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29647889/16938559). It works very well.